# How to automate switching from App introduction page to Home page in appium using selenium

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am new to appium-andriod. Writing the script for one app. In that I have to switch App introduction pages to Main Login Activity. How to do that?

Comment: Do you need to switch app or do you just need to switch screen of the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can start new activity as shown below

**1. Create Activity class object**

```
   Activity activity = new Activity("app package goes here", "app activity goes here");
```

**2. Pass object to startActivity method**

```
    driver.startActivity(activity);
```

**3. You can add waits if required based on appPackage or appActivity names**

```
       activity.setWaitAppPackage("app wait package goes here");
       activity.setWatAppActivity("app wait activity goes here");
```

4. Usage as test method

   ```
   @Test 
    public void startActivityInThisAppTestCase() {
     Activity activity = new Activity("app package goes here", 
       "app activity goes here");
     driver.startActivity(activity);
     assertEquals(driver.currentActivity(),
       "app switched activity goes here");
   ```

   }

> > If you want to see more test cases of Activity class follow this [link](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/1991a8a0f9e4a3ff467dbb713cb5c51c8edc060f/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidActivityTest.java)
> >
> > If you want to see library details of startActivity method follow this [link](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/StartsActivity.html#startActivity-io.appium.java_client.android.Activity-)